# Testflight doesn't send carash reports

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a test application in which I have a crash inside in order to test testflight, but I don't receive any crash logs.

I have checked "Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from apple" during the upload to app store.

Also in my device  I have enabled the Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage I have checked the "Automatically send" and "Share with App Developers".

In  Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostic & usage Data
of my iOS device I can see the crashlogs but I can't see the crash logs in the organizer in the crashes tab.